# How can I find a directory-diff of millions of files to script maintenance?

Tags: shell, directory

I have been working on how to verify that millions of files that were on file system A have infact been moved to file system B. While working on a system migration, it became evident that all the files needed to be audited to prove that the files have been moved. The files were initially moved via rsync, which does provide logs, although not in a format that is helpful for doing an audit. So, I wrote this script to index all the files on System A:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Get directories and file list to be used to verify proper file moves have worked     successfully.
LOGDATE=`/usr/bin/date +%Y-%m-%d`
FILE_LIST_OUT=/mounts/A_files_$LOGDATE.txt
MOUNT_POINTS="/mounts/AA mounts/AB"

touch $FILE_LIST_OUT 
echo TYPE,USER,GROUP,BYTES,OCTAL,OCTETS,FILE_NAME > $FILE_LIST_OUT
for directory in $MOUNT_POINTS; do
    # format: type,user,group,bytes,octal,octets,file_name
    gfind $directory -mount -printf "%y","%u","%g","%s","%m","%p\n" >> $FILE_LIST_OUT

done
```

The file indexing works fine and takes about two hours to index ~30 million files.

On side B is where we run into issues. I have written a very simple shell script that reads the index file, tests to see if the file is there, and then counts up how many files are there, but it's running out of memory while looping through the 30 million lines on indexed file names. Effectively doing this little bit of code below through a while loop, and counters to increment for files found and not found.

```
if [ -f "$TYPE" "$FILENAME" ] ; then
print file found 
++
else 
file not found 
++
fi
```

My questions are:

1. Can a shell script do this type of reporting from such a large list. A 64 bit unix system ran out of memory while trying to execute this script. I have already considered breaking up the input script into smaller chunks to make it faster. Currently it can
2. If as shell script is inappropriate, what would you suggest?

Comment: I now think the memory issues are external to the script.

Comment: Maybe move this to serverfault admins. -OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just used rsync, use it again...

> **--ignore-existing**
>
> This tells rsync to skip updating files that already exist on the destination (this does not ignore existing directories, or nothing would get done).  See also --existing.
>
> This  option  is  a  transfer  rule,  not an exclude, so it doesn’t affect the data that goes into the file-lists, and thus it doesn’t affect deletions.  It just limits the files that the receiver requests to be transferred.
>
> This option can be useful for those doing backups using the --link-dest option when they need to continue a backup run that got interrupted.  Since a --link-dest run is copied into a  new directory  hierarchy  (when  it  is  used  properly),  using  --ignore  existing  will ensure that the already-handled files don’t get tweaked (which avoids a change in permissions on the hard-linked files).  This does mean that this option is only looking at the existing files in the destination hierarchy itself.

That will actually fix any problems (at least in the same sense that any diff-list on file-exist tests could fix problem. Using `--ignore-existing` means `rsync` only does the file-exist tests (so it'll construct the diff list as you request and use it internally). If you just want information on the differences, check `--dry-run`, and `--itemize-changes`.

Lets say you have two directories, `foo` and `bar`. Let's say `bar` has three files, `1`,`2`, and `3`. Let's say that `bar`, has a directory `quz`, which has a file `1`. The directory `foo` is empty:

Now, here is the result,

```
$ rsync -ri --dry-run --ignore-existing ./bar/ ./foo/
>f+++++++++ 1
>f+++++++++ 2
>f+++++++++ 3
cd+++++++++ quz/
>f+++++++++ quz/1
```

Note, you're not interested in the **cd+++++++++** -- that's just showing you that `rsync` issued a `chdir`. Now, let's add a file in `foo` called `1`, and let's use `grep` to remove the `chdir`(s),

```
$ rsync -ri --dry-run --ignore-existing ./bar/ ./foo/ | grep -v '^cd'
>f+++++++++ 2
>f+++++++++ 3
>f+++++++++ quz/1
```

**f** is for file. The **+++++++++** means the file doesn't exist in the DEST dir.

Here is the bonus, remove `--dry-run`, and, it'll go ahead and make the changes for you.

Comment: +1 as this addresses the real task which got buried in a confusion of scripting.

Comment: This is a good suggestion. One of the problems I am having with rsync is how long it is taking to process the source side. It's an older version of rsync (procedurally, not technically) and can't be upgraded. I was originally hoping that scripting would reduce this time to a couple of hours, but rsync without transfers would take only a couple of hours to run. Currently, rsync takes about 2 hours just to index 1/8th of the files. Originally I wanted the script to verify size or do a cksum, but both those operations we going to take way to long. Also, an audit needs readable entries for files.

Comment: BTW, these types of problems are usually more fit for serverfault, and you may want to flag your question and ask that they migrate it to serverfault.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered a solution such as [kdiff3](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/), which will diff directories of files ?

Note the feature for version 0.9.84

> Directory-Comparison: Option "Full Analysis" allows to show the number
>   of solved vs. unsolved conflicts or deltas vs. whitespace-changes in
>   the directory tree.

Answer (score 0):

1. There is absolutely no problem reading a 30 million line file in a shell script. The reason why your process failed was most likely that you tried to read the file entirely into memory, e.g. by doing something wrong like `for i in $(cat file)`.
   The correct way of reading a file is:

   ```
   while IFS= read -r line
     do
       echo "Something with $line"
   done < someFile
   ```
2. A shell script is inappropriate, yes. You should be using a diff tool:

   ```
   diff -rNq /original /new
   ```

Comment: This is interesting. This is exactly what my script does. I think the problem with memory is external to the script. I actually had two scripts running. One that wrote to a log, the other that just incremented variables to be mailed out when it finished. The one that is writing to disk kept running while the other one died. Luck of the draw I would say. 
In point 2 you say to use diff, I'm not sure how this would work across two different systems. i.e. The mounts are not shared on the same systems.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not particular about the solution being a script, you could also look into [meld](http://meldmerge.org/), which would let you diff directory trees quite easily and you can also set ignore patterns if you have any.